# Flutter dynamic data in a container

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I must say I am impressed comming from a c# background I was able to do a listview in under five mins that were horizontal and contained a few containers.

However, I would like my container to be dynamically showing a List contents what I have so far is a widget building my colours out

```
 Widget horizontalList2 = new Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    height: 200.0,
    child: new ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.blue,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.green,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.cyan,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.black,   
    child:Text("Test"),

    child: Image.network(
          'https://flutter.io/images/catalog-widget-placeholder.png',
          height: 100,
          width: 150
        ) 

    )
```

But as you see I am trying to create another text element I want image then a bit of text and another text much the same way as Netflix would work but it's for a weather app.

Can someone explain how the child elements works can ou not have more than one child in a container cause when i tried this i got the following error. And what I should do to have a second child element of text and base the listview of a Dynamic POCO List

> The [child] contained by the container.
>
> If null, and if the [constraints] are unbounded or also null, the container will expand to fill all available space in its parent, unless the parent provides unbounded constraints, in which case the container will attempt to be as small as possible.

Comment: If you want to put more elements you can use `Column` or `Row` and they take `children` as an argument

Answer (score 1):

You should use Multi-child layout widget, these accept `children` instead of `child`. A good example for you might be `Row`, `Column` or `Stack`.

Don't be scared of nesting your Widgets, you'll be doing it a lot!

```
ListView
  Container
    Row
      Text
      Image
      Icon
  Container
    Row
      Text
      Image
      Icon
```

When you find yourself repeating your widget tree like this, create a custom widget that outputs the subtree. The above might become:

```
ListView
  MyColoredListItem
  MyColoredListItem
```

You can find a full list of Multi-child layout widgets on the flutter docs here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets

For more information about creating your own widgets:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: after frustrations with xamrain while i love the idea and concept being a developer from .net the front end is lacking easy to use things